# GuzzleHttp Client:CURL error 3: <url> malformed

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I currently new for this GuzzleHttp, I read some post in other site they teach how it GuzzleHttp Work in API Request. I have question why Guzzle give me error like this if my api is this

```
$response = $client->get('/api/first_data');
```

[image: Error]

if my api look this show correct

```
$response = $client->get('https://play.geokey.org.uk/api/projects/77');
```

[image: Show output]

This my controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use DateTime;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ContentController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function first_data() {

        $table_slider = DB::select('SELECT content_id,link,file,slider_sorting,content_pages FROM content_structure as cs LEFT JOIN (SELECT cid,file FROM content_upload_assets) cua ON cs.content_id = cua.cid WHERE content_pages = ? AND cs.status = ? ORDER BY content_id DESC ',[

            'Slider',
            'Active'

        ]);

        return response()->json($table_slider);
    }

    public function fetch_first_data() {

         $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'localhost:8000']);
         $response = $client->get('/api/first_data');

         $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
         $project = json_decode($body);
        dd($project);
    }
}
```

The API response if i browse the localhost:8000/api/first_data
[image: my api]

My API route:

```
Route::get('first_data','ContentController@first_data');
```

My Web.php Route:

```
Route::get('/fetch_first_data','ContentController@fetch_first_data');
```

Comment: Well, what do you expect Guzzle to do? The given URL is invalid, that's the point. Just try to use it in your browser (in that exact form!)

Comment: @NicoHaase i can access exactly the url. i will update my post so you will see if the url is invalid thanks.

Comment: You type `/api/first_data` into your browser, without a protocol or a host name, and something happens?

Comment: @NicoHaase Hi. what do you mean for that.. ?

Answer (score 2):

Add **http://** as prefix to your  URI

```
 $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000']);
```

(make sure)

Answer (score 1):

Guzzle does not assume that all requests are based on, by default, the URI of the application you run it in. For example, if your application is running at

```
https://example.org
```

and you try to call

```
$client->get('/api/first_data');
```

Guzzle will **not** assume you mean to call

```
$client->get('https://example.org/api/first_data');
```

Guzzle does not have any concept of what site you are running in, only the endpoint of what it is trying to call. Instead, you must use the complete *full* uri of the call using either

```
$client->get('https://example.org/api/first_data');
```

as mentioned above, or set the base URI in the Client config

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://example.org']);
$response = $client->get('/api/first_data');
```

Comment: hi jason. i just run my project in localhost only.. is this will work?

Comment: if i use that. my browser is looping

Comment: You've almost answered your own question. The base URI, in your case, would be http://localhost:8000

Comment: There's most likely something else wrong in your application. Paste your routes to these controllers into your question.

Comment: Please also add any updates you have made to your controllers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185472/discussion-between-devge-and-jason).

Comment: If something is "looping", you should start debugging. This could happen through simple `var_dump` calls, or better some kind of debugger like XDebug. If you know what is going wrong, edit your question to contain all information